# TypeError: require(...).listen is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, server, socket.io

I wrote this, but errors come up and i dont know how to fix

```
var http = require('http');
var clientHtml = require('fs').readFileSync('client.html');

var plainHttpServer = http.createServer(function (request, response) {
response.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });
response.end(clientHtml);
}).listen(8080);

var files = require('fs');

var io = require('socket.io').listen(plainHttpServer);
io.set('origins', ['localhost:8080', '127.0.0.1:8080']);
```

and this error comes, i don't know how to fix, tell me

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(plainHttpServer);
                          ^

TypeError: require(...).listen is not a function
```

Comment: yes, @Abra is correct, this looks like javascript. However, the error is saying that require() does not return something that you can use the function listen() with

Comment: Have you installed the Node package socket.io? In your command line, in the directory that contains that node script, do `npm install socket.io`.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`require('socket.io')` returns the socket.io Server class.  It's a class, not an instance and thus not something you call `.listen()` on.  Depending upon what exactly you're trying to accomplish, there are a number of different ways you can use that Server class as you can see [here in the doc](https://socket.io/docs/v3/server-api/#new-Server-httpServer-options).  For example, you can do this:

```
const Server = require('socket.io');
const io = new Server(somePort);
```

or this:

```
const io = require('socket.io')(somePort);
```

or to share an existing http server:

```
const io = require('socket.io')(plainHttpServer);
```

Comment: Just to add to this - versions prior to the latest did support the listen() function

Comment: In case any `Strapi` developer encounter this `error` try `const io = require('socket.io')(strapi.server.httpServer);`

Answer (score 7):

The below snippet worked for me:

```
const io = require('socket.io')(server);
...
server.listen(3000)
```

Answer (score 2):

Do Simply Updated Code here:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
server.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);
console.log('Server is running ');
```

Answer (score -1):

you need to add cors properly to this and set client request url in cors

```
const { Server } = require("socket.io")

const cors = require("cors");

app.use(cors());


const server = http.createServer(app)

const io = new Server(server,{

    cors: {
        origin: "http://localhost:3002"  <--- here add client req url 
    }
});
```

Comment: No. Giving permission for cross-origin requests to access the server will not solve the problem that the command to start the server in the first place is throwing an error.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).