# socket.io - socket.on() doesn't receive data

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io

I am working on a project with socketio in Nodejs and as far as I can tell my emit() works perfectly fine

emit() seems to work, at least there is no error message at that point.
I also get the client connection confirmed in the server console. The connection is established - but the emitted "data" never arrives (I get no console output after the console log)

Does anybody have a hint?

here is my code:

app.js

```js
var SerialPort = require("serialport");
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');

var index = fs.readFileSync('index.html');

const parsers = SerialPort.parsers;
const parser = new parsers.Readline({
    delimiter: '\r\n'
});

var port = new SerialPort('COM3', {
    baudRate: 9600,
    dataBits: 8,
    parity: 'none',
    stopBits: 1,
    flowControl: false
})


port.pipe(parser);


var app = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type':'text/html'});
    res.end(index);
});

var io = require('socket.io').listen(app);

io.on('connection', function(data) {
    console.log("Nodejs is listening");
});

parser.on('data', function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    io.emit('data', data);
});



app.listen(3000);
```

index.html

```html
  

  <html>
        <header>
            <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/4.5.0/socket.io.js"></script>
        </header>

        <body>
            <div id="speed">0</div>km/h
            <script>
                var socket = io();
                console.log("socket open");
                socket.on('data', function(data) {
                    console.log(data);
                });
            </script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: I think you should add the link of your server in your `io()` function in the html file. Example: `var socket = io('http://localhost:3000');`

Comment: Doesn't make a difference unfortunately.

Comment: I found the issue. I think it was the old (2.0.4..) version of socket.io I implemented in package.json.
After using the most up to date, I had to replace require().listen(app) with require().(server) and everything worked

reference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64923775/typeerror-require-listen-is-not-a-function/66479806#66479806